# INCLUDE hint on User-Defined Table Types TSQL 2016

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to add a Non clustered index on a tvt - something along the lines of ...

```
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (row_number) INCLUDE (event_datetime, venue_id)
```

is this not allowed on TVTs?

Thanks,

Erich

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot!

A nonclustered index cannot be created on a user-defined table type unless the index is the result of creating a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint on the user-defined table type. (SQL Server enforces any UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint by using an index.)

You can see more about restriction on UDT's here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx